# AWS CLI ALB: Modify default action of http listener to redirect

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-cli, aws-application-load-balancer

I am trying to modify default action of a http listener in ALB to redirect using awscli. This is to redirect traffic on HTTP listener to HTTPS listener.

I am trying the below command but it fails.
Can someone please help me with this. How can I add redirect config in command ?

AWSCLI documentation doesn't seem to be much helpful in this.

```
aws elbv2 modify-listener --listener-arn $LISTENER_ARN --default-actions Type=redirect,RedirectConfig={Protocol=HTTPS,Port=443,Host=#{host},Path=/#{path},Query=#{query},StatusCode=HTTP_301}
```

Error:

```
Error parsing parameter '--default-actions': Expected: ',', received: '}' for input: Type=redirect,RedirectConfig=Host=#{host}
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the error message on failure?

Comment: @kenlukas Error parsing parameter '--default-actions': Expected: ',', received: '}' for input:
Type=redirect,RedirectConfig=Host=#{host}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect config should be like this

```
aws elbv2 modify-listener --listener-arn <listener> --default-actions '[{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": {"Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "Host": "#{host}", "Query": "#{query}", "Path": "/#{path}", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}]'
```